# Animated content using Jquery & Ajax

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, gallery

I'm not really a developer though I was able to implement some small Jquery scripts. However I've been stuck for a month now researching for a certain functionality that I want to apply. I was wondering if you have any tutorials or answers on how to implement this kind of gallery/project preview as seen here on http://blacktie.es. That when clicking on a thumbmail, a panel slides down and shows the content. I was thinking it was maybe implemented with Ajax. All help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: start practicing Jquery Plugins for image sliders.
They are easy & don't require any expertise to use.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this gallery is premade, since you're not really a developer I suggest you to look for a premade gallery (searching on google for "jQuery Slideshow" you should find what you're looking for).

For example, you can find a nice flash slide show => http://www.modularweb.net/#/en/piecemaker/

Hope this help.

Aymeric.

Answer (score 0):

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) is your friend. First, seems like the site you mentioned is using [scrollTo](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) plugin along with [Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

He's using a combination of three Jquery plugins:

Cycle
ScrollTo
Touchwipe

These will achieve your desired effect.

AJAX doesn't seem necessary.